# Foreign key without constraints?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I was studying `DataRelations` in Ado.Net and came across this constructor

```
public DataRelation(
    string relationName,
    DataColumn parentColumn,
    DataColumn childColumn,
    bool createConstraints
)
```

Here, the last parameter is `createConstraints`, which is explained by MSDN as

> createConstraints
>
> Type: System.Boolean
>
> A value that indicates whether constraints are created. true, if
>   constraints are created. Otherwise, false.

If I set it to `false` then what happens? How does it create a foreign key without constraints?

Comment: "*What happens*" - Try it and tell us :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the relationship will be created without a constraint being added to `ConstraintCollection`

More on constraints:

> Relationships can also cascade various changes from the parent DataRow
>   to its child rows. To control how values are changed in child rows,
>   add a ForeignKeyConstraint to the ConstraintCollection of the
>   DataTable object. The ConstraintCollection determines what action to
>   take when a value in a parent table is deleted or updated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz0az7c7.aspx

Comment: So if I set it to false, absolutely no action will be taken if the parent is updated or deleted?

Comment: Yes; which part of the documentation is confusing to you?

Comment: `When a DataRelation is created, it first verifies that the relationship can be established. After it is added to the DataRelationCollection, the relationship is maintained by disallowing any changes that would invalidate it. Between the period when a DataRelation is created and added to the DataRelationCollection, it is possible for additional changes to be made to the parent or child rows. An exception is generated if this causes a relationship that is no longer valid` Then wouldn't the relationship become invalid for the child tuples if I delete the parent tuple that they were connected to?

Comment: Only if you do it `Between the period when a DataRelation is created and added to the DataRelationCollection`